# Scala nested loops yield

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop

I wonder if there is a simple way to do something like this in scala:

```
case class Pot(width: Int, height: Int, flowers: Seq[FlowerInPot])
case class FlowerInPot(x: Int, y: Int, flower: String)

val flowers = Seq("tulip", "rose")
val height = 3
val width = 3

val res =
  for (flower <- flowers;
       h <- 0 to height;
       w <- 0 to width) yield {
       // ??
  }
```

and at an output I'd like to have a Seq of Pots with all possible combinations of flowers placed in it. So in following example, the output should be:

```
Seq(
  Pot(3, 3, Seq(FlowerInPot(0, 0, "tulip"), FlowerInPot(0, 1, "rose"))),
  Pot(3, 3, Seq(FlowerInPot(0, 0, "tulip"), FlowerInPot(0, 2, "rose"))),
  Pot(3, 3, Seq(FlowerInPot(0, 0, "tulip"), FlowerInPot(1, 0, "rose"))),
  Pot(3, 3, Seq(FlowerInPot(0, 0, "tulip"), FlowerInPot(1, 1, "rose"))),
  ...
  Pot(3, 3, Seq(FlowerInPot(2, 2, "tulip"), FlowerInPot(2, 1, "rose")))
)
```

any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to have two flower generators, like `flowerA <- flowers` and `flowerB <- flowers`

Comment: It seem to be good direction, but what if I have n types of flowers instead of fixed 2?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
case class FlowerInPot(x: Int, y: Int, flower: String)
case class Pot(width: Int, height: Int, flowers: Seq[FlowerInPot])

val x, y = 0
val flowers = Seq("tulip", "rose")
val height = 3
val width = 3

val res = for {
  h <- 0 to height
  w <- 0 to width
} yield Pot(height, width, flowers.map(flower => FlowerInPot(w, h, flower)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solutions always places all flowers in each pot on the same position. Instead of finding all possible combinations of positions.

Comment: @gysyky I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you provide a minimal, but complete, expected output for a given input?

Comment: Hi, for example for width = 2 and height = 2 and the same flowers, the output should be ( I omit pot width, height as it's always 2 in this case): 
Seq(
      (0, 0, "tulip"), (0, 1, "rose")
      0, 0, "tulip"), (1, 0, "rose")
      0, 0, "tulip"), (1, 1, "rose")
      1, 0, "tulip"), (0, 1, "rose")
      1, 0, "tulip"), (1, 1, "rose")
      1, 0, "tulip"), (0, 1, "rose")
      1, 1, "tulip"), (0, 1, "rose")
      1, 1, "tulip"), (1, 0, "rose")
      1, 1, "tulip"), (0, 0, "rose")
      0, 1, "tulip"), (1, 0, "rose")
      0, 1, "tulip"), (0, 0, "rose")
      0, 1, "tulip"), (1, 1, "rose")

Comment: Arghh, cannot format it nice in comment. I think it's similar to problem of finding all possible combinations to place figures on w*h chessboard.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for now this solution seems to work:

```
 val res = for {
  h <- 0 to height;
  w <- 0 to width;
  flower <- flowers
} yield (h, w, flower)

val pots: Seq[Pot] = res.sliding(flowers.size).map(l => Pot(width, height, l.map(f => FlowerInPot(f._1, f._2, f._3)))).toList
```